# Laravel / nested validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I am building a component-driven API for a basic page-builder system and have hit a stumbling block when it comes to validation.

First, I want to explain the use-case.

if we have a component (for example in Vue) in `/components/ProfileCard.vue`

```html
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        name: String,
        age: Number,
        avatar: String
    }
}
</script>
```

I am creating a component in the backend  `components.php` config:

```php
<?php

return [
    'profile' => [
        'component' => 'ProfileCard',
        'rules' => [
            'name' => [
                'required',
            ],
            'age' => [
                'required',
                'number',
            ],
            'avatar' => [
                'required',
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

Which checks and validates every time a profile card component is submitted.

Creating a custom validation rule for Component, I am able to say "the ProfileCard component is not valid" but I am not able to merge / nest the validation rules:

`Component.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class Component implements Rule 
{
    protected $validator = null;

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $components = config('components');
        $component = $value['component'];

        if (isset($components[$component])) {
            return false;
        }

        $c = $components[$component];
        $this->validator = Validator::make($value['data'], $c['rules'], $c['messages'] ?? '');
        return $this->validator->passes();
    }

    public function message() 
    {
        if (is_null($this->validator)) {
            return 'The component does not exist';
        }
        return $this->validator->errors();
    }
}
```

Has anybody got any experience doing anything like this or can anybody point me in the right direction towards a solution?

I am ideally looking for a solution which is applicable while using Laravel's FormRequest validation, like so:

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Unique;
use App\Rules\Component;

class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'email',
                new Unique('users', 'email'),
            ],
            'profile' => [
                'required',
                new Component(),
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

The data would come in like so:

```
{
    "email": "test@example.com",
    "profile": {
        "component": "ProfileCard",
        "data": {
           "name": "Test",
           "age": 49,
           "avatar": "https://example.com/avatar.png"
        }
    }
}
```

I have updated the question with the progress I have made myself, you can return a `MessageBag` in the `messages` method on the rule, however, this creates a slight problem, the response comes back as follows:

```
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "profile": [
            {
                "name": [
                    "The name field is required."
                ],
                "age": [
                    "The age field is required."
                ],
                "avatar": [
                    "The avatar field is required."
                ],
            },
            ":message"
        ]
    }
```

Clearly this is an improvement but it's still not as usable, we don't have a ':message' and the validation errors are nested in an object in the "profile" array.

Comment: Can you post your rules please? And what class they're in etc.

Comment: I have updated the question with some progress I have made and more information about the problem.

Comment: What do you get when you `dd($this->validator->errors()->getMessages());` or is that the exact same as your final code snippet in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems like you are over complicating a simple problem. I would never do a validation in a validation rule. Instead do rules that is dependent on the `component` and adjust it in the form request accordingly. You can easily do nested rules like so.

```
[
    'profile.name' => 'string',
]
```

Do the rest of the logic in the form request. The strategy is to have rules based on the request input and your config file, based on what you already tried.

```
public function rules()
{
    // i do not know how you determine this key
    $componentKey = 'profile';

    $rules = [
        ...,
        $componentKey => [
            'required',
        ]
    ];

    $inputComponent= $this->input('profile')['component'];
    $components = config('components');

    // based on your data this seems wrong, but basically fetch the correct config entry
    $component = $components[$inputComponent];

    foreach ($component['rules'] as $key => $value) {
            $rules[$componentKey  . '.' . $key] => $value;
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

There is some parts of your code where i can't figure out what your data means, i do not know how you get the component key profile and your code based on the config and the component field seems wrong and should instead do a loop with a where condition. I think that this can get you in the right direction, this solution will solve your message problem and be way simpler.

Comment: I am aware of the ability to nest validation using dot-syntax, what I am trying to achieve is to have dynamically generated content on a page, such as a page builder which will have different component types, for instance a "list" component or a "hero" component, which will need different data to be validated depending which is selected. The ProfileComponent is here for example purposes. Your answer does solve the problem, although in a way I hoped to avoid, creating a messy "rules" method. It does appear that this is the only way to do this so I'm happy to mark your answer as correct!

Comment: I dont think this will be more messy then the road you where going down on which where validation in a validation. In each component model you can make the methods to generate the rules and you will be allright

Comment: Checking the internals, I can see why nested validation the way I was trying to is not implemented, it leaves too many places for mistakes to happen and makes using the validation message data a lot more difficult!